# What's the applied use of getBytes/encoding a string into a sequence of bytes

Tags: java, string, byte

Just now I learned about the Java getBytes method. It encodes a string into a sequence of bytes and stores it in a byte array. See below example.

As with many Java methods, I wonder what's its use? Why/when would you want to convert a String (char) into a byte code?

```
String str = "Java";
byte[] byteArray = str.getBytes();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));
```

Comment: Usually for [Serialization](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm), which is typically use to store objects/data in secondary memory.

Answer (score 1):

You need bytes for binary data, for instance for storing a String to a file.

There is an overloaded method, that specifies the encoding the bytes must be in. Your `getBytes()` uses the default OS encoding.

```
byte[] byteArray = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

str = new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

As `String` can combine text in the full Unicode range, Greek, Arab, math symbols etcetera, there is always a conversion to binary data.

It is crucial for storing and loading text from binary data, especially as binary data misses the information of its encoding.

It was a design decision to let Java text hold the full Unicode in `String`.
They did this as an array of UTF-16 `char`, every `char` a 2 byte value.

Comment: I think it's misleading to refer to text as "binary data".  Yes, I know all data is bits.  Nevertheless, if a file contains the bytes 68 65 6C 6C 6F 0A, we generally regard that as text, not binary: we look at it and see a line containing "hello".

Comment: @user16632363 I wanted to make a distinction between _text_ on the one side, and _binary data_ together with its encoding/Charset on the other side, I marked your comment as helpful. The point is: your file is in java just _binary data_, but as soon as there is a conversion (to String) then it is _text_. For that to be possible someone must say which encoding/Charset the bytes are in. Your file on an AS/400 computer would not be text, as it does not use ASCII but EBCDIC: "  %$?`SMM`".

Comment: Once again, I disagree.  Alphanumerics in EBCDIC are text. ASCII is not the only legitimate text encoding.  Text is, more or less, values which correspond to marks (traditionally on paper, but not so constrained for computers) that are meaningful to humans.  Even in Java terms, if you look at (say) PrintWriter, it'll tell you it writes output to a **text output stream**.

Comment: @user16632363 I think we disagree on semantics, I make a distinction between String, char, *Reader, *Wrter - text -, and byte, InputStream, OutputStream - binary data -. There is always a Charset conversion between them, a Charset specifying the encoding of the data. Probably I expressed myself too rigorously. So: binary data can also be non-textual. Binary data + Charset can be text. Or binary data can be not entirely specified text (charset missing as decoding key). That you call _text_ too. Rightly so I admit.

Answer (score 1):

> Serialization is the process of converting Java objects into a stream
> of bytes. The stream of bytes can be transmitted through a network
> connection, stored in a database as a BLOB object or saved as a binary
> file. The stored or transmitted stream of bytes can be reconstructed
> to Java object later. This article explains Serialization in Java,
> using a simple step by step example.

Source: https://www.javahelps.com/2015/07/serialization-in-java.html